# Implementing CRUD in MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-mvc, crud

I'm still new to MVC. now in my controller I want to perform basic CRUD such as Create, Edit, Details.

I use MySql as the database.

When I run the program in debug mode, it shows no error. But, in create page, when I click "submit" button, the new data entered is not updated in the index. I was wondering why and need help here.

Could you guys tell me where in create and edit I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

controller:

```
    //GET UserActivity/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        string sqlQuery = @"
          SELECT ua.Id
            ,ua.CreatedBy
            ,ua.CreatedOn
            ,ua.ModifiedBy
            ,ua.ModifiedOn
            ,ua.ContactId
            ,ua.EntityName
            ,ua.EntityId
            ,ua.StatusCode
            ,ua.StateCode
            ,ua.ActivityType
            ,ua.ActivityStatus
            ,ua.DueDate
            ,ua.ActualEndDate
            ,ua.MasqueradeOn
            ,ua.MasqueradeBy 

            FROM UserActivity ua
            INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.Id = ua.ContactId
            WHERE ua.id = @UserActivityId
        ";

        UserActivityModels userActivity = null;

        using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection
            (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMPORTALSQLCONN"].
            ConnectionString))
        {
            userActivity = (UserActivityModels)db.Query<UserActivityModels>(sqlQuery
               , new
               {
                   @UserActivityId = id
               }).FirstOrDefault();

        }
        return View(userActivity);
    }

    /* // POST: /UserActivity/Details
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    */


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    //GET /UserActivity/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View();
    }


    //
    // POST: /UserActivity/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            /*
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                userActivity.Add(useractivity);
                */
            UserActivityModels useractivity = new UserActivityModels();

            int Id = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Id"]);
            int CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Created By"]);
            DateTime CreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["Created On"]);
            int ModifiedBy = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Modified By"]);
            DateTime ModifiedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["Modified On"]);
            string ContactId = collection["Contact Id"];
            int StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Status Code"]);
            int StateCode = Convert.ToInt32(collection["State Code"]);
            string EntityName = collection["Entity Name"];
            int EntityId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Entity Id"]);
            DateTime DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["Due Date"]);
            DateTime ActualEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["Actual EndDate"]);
            DateTime MasqueradeOn = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["Masquerade On"]);
            DateTime MasqueradeBy = Convert.ToDateTime(collection["Masquerade By"]);
            string ContactName = collection["Contact Name"];

            userActivity.Add(useractivity);


            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        catch
        {
            return View();
        }

    }




    //---------------------------------------------------------------------//



    // GET: /UserActivity/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMPORTALSQLCONN"].ConnectionString);
        string query = @"
          SELECT ua.Id
            ,ua.CreatedBy
            ,ua.CreatedOn
            ,ua.ModifiedBy
            ,ua.ModifiedOn
            ,ua.ContactId
            ,ua.EntityName
            ,ua.EntityId
            ,ua.StatusCode
            ,ua.StateCode
            ,ua.ActivityType
            ,ua.ActivityStatus
            ,ua.DueDate
            ,ua.ActualEndDate
            ,ua.MasqueradeOn
            ,ua.MasqueradeBy 
    ,concat(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS ContactName
            FROM UserActivity ua
            INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.Id = ua.ContactId
            WHERE ua.id = @userActivityId

        ";

        UserActivityModels userActivity = null;

        using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["CRMPORTALSQLCONN"].ConnectionString))
        {
            // userActivity = (UserActivityModels)db.Query<UserActivityModels>(query);


            userActivity = db.Query<UserActivityModels>(query
                , new
                {
                    @UserActivityId = id
                }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return View(userActivity);
    }

    // POST: /UserActivity/Edit/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(userActivity);

    }


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    // GET: /UserActivity/Delete/
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /SavedCar/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {


        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

userActivity Model:

```
 public class UserActivityModels
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created On")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modified By")]
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modified On")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]   
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Id")]
    public string ContactId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Entity Name")]
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Entity Id")]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status Code")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State Code")]
    public int StateCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Activity Type")]
    public int ActivityType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Activity Status")]
    public string ActivityStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DueDate")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Actual EndDate")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ActualEndDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Masquerade On")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime MasqueradeOn { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Masquerade By")]
    public int MasqueradeBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Name")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Title is really misleading. The problem is your Code doesn't communicate with your MySQL Database. Not CRUD or MVC...

Answer (score 1):

In your update method, you should be grabbing the model then feeding it to the database.

Here's a couple of simple examples:

```
[Post]
public ActionResult Add(User u) {
     // Need to define 'db' as a Data connection
     db.Users.Add(u);
     db.SubmitChanges();
     return View(u);
}


[Post]
public ActionResult Update(User u) {
     // Need to define 'db' as a Data connection
     var updatedUser = db.Users.Where(k=>k.Id == u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
     updatedUser = u;
     db.SubmitChanges();
     return View(updatedUser);
}
```

Comment: what if I use db from MySql? is that mean I need to use MySql connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an element only to `userActivity` is not updating the **database**.So every time when you trying to show the page, it recreating a **new controller** and also a **new userActivity**.To solve this, in the `Create Action`,you must add the new useractivity into database, not into `userActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

In Create Post Controller you have

```
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Id"]);
```

If the Id is auto-increment, you just put int Id=0 or you don't need to provide it. If you provide Id by yourself, it may duplicate and insert cannot be done.
With regards to edit view, it's important to have Id hidden, so that you can really update the correct Id. Do check the followings:
- Your mysql table structure
- Remove Id field in create view
- Add hidden Id field in edit view
- Check your controllers.

Comment: Looking at your controller int CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Created By"]);, I don't think form collection posting back values with spaces like "Created By"... Try to debug to see what happens.